# Placing a view in RelativeLayout android by giving specific positions

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place a view by giving giving specific coordinates i.e the top and the left margin of the layout but somehow the top positioning is not working as expected.
this is how i am doing it

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            200, 200);
    // this will make the top left corner as 0,0
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = x1;
    layoutParams.topMargin = y1;
```

It works correctly if i give a smaller value for top margin but the larger the value the bigger the error is.
For example on a screen with height 800 if i give top margin value as 400 , it should be be starting from middle , atleast thats what i expect but it is starting from around the 60% of screen and if i start it from 720 which is 90% of the screen , it is not even showing.
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly have something to do with the layout it is inflated in!!! Have you applies any weights to it?

Comment: Can you post your layout file?